# How to handle NULL or NOT NULL in DROOLS

Tags: null, drools, business-rules, drools-guvnor

I have created a rule

```
rule "NullCheck_Rule1"
salience 1
dialect "mvel"
date-effective "16-Nov-2017 00:00"
no-loop  
when 
$cdr : JSONObject( $cdr.optString("name") == null)   
then
$cdr.put("Action_1" ,"SEND MAIL");end
```

and for not null

```
rule "NullCheck_Rule1"
salience 1
dialect "mvel"
date-effective "16-Nov-2017 00:00"
no-loop  
when
$cdr : JSONObject( $cdr.optString("name") != null)   
then
$cdr.put("Action_1" , "SEND MAIL");end
```

and my input is something like this `"{\"id\":100,\"name\":null,\"city\":\"Pune\"}"`

But its not matching the conditions even if I used condition like  `$cdr.optString("name") IS NULL` OR `$cdr.optString("name") IS NOT NULL`

So how to handle null and not null in drools. The version of drools which I am using is 6.5.0.Final.

Comment: Several possibilities: (1) there is no JSONObject ni Working Memory. (2) The JSONObject does not have a component optString. (3) The rule fires but you have failed to check correctly that the `put` works.

Comment: For the point (1) I am converting JSONString to JSONObject. So there is JSONObject in working memory (2) The optString is available in JSONObject. You can refer this https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: Use a rule with just `JSONObject()` - i.e., no constraint - and a println of the result of  `$cdr.optString("name")` as the consequence. Does it fire? What does it print? -- If it doesn't fire, you don't have such a fact in Working MEmory.

Comment: It works If my rule is `JSONObject( $cdr.optString("name") == "")`  and even with `JSONObject( $cdr.isNull("name"))` but not with `JSONObject( $cdr.optString("name") == null)`

Comment: Not using any JSON but coding plain Java + DRL, both rules (using ==null and !=null) work in 5.5.0.  - If it is a bug, it won't be fixed in that old version. If you add your Java (!) class for JSONObject to the question, I might have a look at it.